# Get person or group field from list then query user profile

Tags: javascript, user-profile, csom, user-profile-property

I am currently working on SharePoint 2013 on premise and I am trying to use JavaScript to get the latest 3 "new starters" from a SharePoint list then return information about them such as the Department, Profile Picture and Full name. I have created a custom list and added a person or group field called "name" and this currently displays the users Account.

I am able to pull the required information from the list however I am struggling to pull in all of the required profile information, this is what i currently have:

```
var web;
var list;
var list;
var mylist;
var collListItem;
var profilePictureUrl;
var accountName;
var username;
var userProfileProperties = [];
var targetUsers = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getNewStarterList);
})

function getNewStarterList() {
    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists();
    mylist = web.get_lists().getByTitle('New Starters');
    var ncamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    ncamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>3</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Name\' /></ViewFields><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'True\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    collListItem = mylist.getItems(ncamlQuery);
    context.load(mylist);
    context.load(collListItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, newstarterSuccessHandler),
     Function.createDelegate(this, newstarterErrorHandler));
}

function newstarterSuccessHandler() {

    listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

        username = oListItem.get_item("Name").get_lookupValue();

        targetUsers.push(username);

        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getNewUserProfile, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
    }

}

function newstarterErrorHandler(sender, args) {
    alert('New Starter Error: \nRequest failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function getNewUserProfile() {

    for (var x = 0; x < targetUsers.length; x++) {
        var user = targetUsers[x];
        alert(user);
    }

    context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context);
    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "PictureURL"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(context, user, profilePropertyNames);

    userProfileProperties = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    context.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

    context.executeQueryAsync(onNewStarterSuccess, onNewStarterFail);
}

function onNewStarterSuccess() {
    //  console.log("succes querying user profiles");
    //console.log('User profile property 1:' + userProfileProperties[1]);
    var nsuserHTML = "";
    profilePictureUrl = userProfileProperties[1];
    alert("Profile Picture: " + profilePictureUrl);
    accountName = userProfileProperties[0];
    alert("username: " + accountName);

}

function onNewStarterFail(sender, args) {
    alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
}
```

I need to be able to pull back the properties to then append to the page layout. I would greatly appreciate any help and advice with how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the accountName for pulling data from the userprofile. You are now using `.get_item("Name").get_lookupValue()` , that gives you the display name. And I don't think there is  `SP.Userprofiles.js` key in the `_v_dictSod`, I have always used the key `userprofile`. Could be SharePoint online thing.

I just pulled your code together some just for a test ( usually I nest it beyond reason when testing in the console), but should be clear enough to see how it could work. Note that you can "batch up" calls, like I do to the userprofile there, instead of 3 calls, you can make one.

Example:

```
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(["sp.js", "userprofile"], getNewStarterList);

function getNewStarterList() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var ncamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    ncamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>3</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\'Name\' /></ViewFields><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Created\' Ascending=\'True\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');

    var collListItems = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("New Starters").getItems(ncamlQuery);
    context.load(collListItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {

        var targetUsers = [];

        var siteUserList = context.get_web().get_siteUserInfoList();

        collListItems.get_data().forEach(function(item,i) {
            if( item.get_item("Name") != null) {

                var userNameItem = siteUserList.getItemById( item.get_item("Name").get_lookupId() );
                targetUsers.push({ 
                        "lookupValue" : item.get_item("Name").get_lookupValue(),
                        "userNameItem": userNameItem
                    });

                context.load( userNameItem, "UserName");

            }
        });

         context.executeQueryAsync(function() {


            var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "PictureURL"];

            targetUsers.forEach(function(ele, i) {

                var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(context, "i:0#.f|membership|"+ ele.userNameItem.get_item("UserName"), profilePropertyNames);
                ele.properties = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(context).getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);

                context.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser); 
            });

            context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                targetUsers.forEach(function(ele, i) {

                    var nsuserHTML = "";
                    var profilePictureUrl = ele.properties[1];
                    console.log( profilePictureUrl );

                });

            }, onFail);


         }, onFail);

     },
     onFail);
}


function onFail(sender, args) {
   console && console.log("Error: " + args.get_message());
}
```